# how to use pandas for set data to csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am a beginner Python programmer.
To get started, I want to add a new column to the dataset and give that column some value.
The solution that came to my mind was to use a repetitive trick.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datasets.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col='Date')

for i in range(100):
    df['zigzag'][i] = sample polynomial
```

But I want you to give me a better idea Like

```
df['25/9/2020','29/9/2020']['zigzag'] = sample polynomial
```

Dataset columns :

> Date , Open , High , Low , Close
>
> 2015-03-02,1215.52,1223,1204.39,1206.38

Comment: `df.loc[['25/9/2020','29/9/2020'],'zigzag'] = sample_polynomial`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you very much It took me a long time.
Can you give me a good training link, please?

Comment: [This official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) about indexing?